# JUnit - How to mock local variable object method call

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

The code for my usecase is below:

My class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class MyClass {
    public String getString() {
        // object need mocking
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        try {
                          // method need mocking
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(List.of("1", "2"));
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
@Test
public void test_get_string() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    Mockito.when(mapper.writeValueAsString(Mockito.anyList()))
          .thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);
    
    Assertions.assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> {
        new MyClass().getString();
    });
    // -> failed
    // Expected RuntimeException but nothing was thrown
}
```

I want to mock the `ObjectMapper` and make it throw `JsonProcessingException` on `writeValueAsString` method call, but the test keeps failing as if it doesn't use my mocked mapper at all. But if I make the mapper a property of `MyClass` and mock it, then the test passes.

```
public class MyClass {
    // make mapper a property
    private ObjectMapper mapper;
    
    public MyClass(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public String getString() {
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(List.of("1", "2"));
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Test
public void test_get_string() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    Mockito.when(mapper.writeValueAsString(Mockito.anyList()))
          .thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);
    
    Assertions.assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> {
        // pass mapper on creating object
        new MyClass(mapper).getString();
    }); // -> success
}
```

In case I don't want to make mapper a property of my class, how should I properly mock it ?

Comment: Why dont you use an object that cannot be serialized instead?

Comment: @Lesiak sorry, I'm pretty new and don't have much insight about the code. Can you explain what and how that would do ?

Comment: `List.of("1", "2")` will serialize correctly. The test checking `JsonProcessingException` makes sense if you pass values that can produce this error. If you have control on what is passed to `writeValueAsString` in your test, you can pass an unserializable object.

Comment: @Lesiak I passed to `writeValueAsString` with `new Object()` and it did throw the exception. But since my actual code always uses a `List<String>` as parameter, I don' think that would do.

Comment: In such case I don't think you will ever encounter this exception when calling `writeValueAsString`. Examples of nonserializable objects include - ones with wrong annotations (2 fields in class annotated with JsonProperty with same name), loops in onject graph etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't mock a local variable declared in a method using Mockito. You can make `ObjectMapper` a  property of your class `MyClass`. But if you don't want to do that, the other option is to add a protected method in your `MyClass` that returns an instance of `ObjectMapper`

```
public class MyClass {
    public String getString() {
        // object need mocking
        ObjectMapper mapper = createObjectMapper()
        try {
                          // method need mocking
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(List.of("1", "2"));
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
   protected ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
       return new ObjectMapper();
   }
}
```

Then in your test case, you can `spy` your class and stub this new method to return a mocked `ObjectMapper` as shown below:

```
@Test
public void test_get_string() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = Mockito.mock(ObjectMapper.class);
    Mockito.when(mapper.writeValueAsString(Mockito.anyList()))
          .thenThrow(JsonProcessingException.class);
    MyClass myClass = Mockito.spy(new MyClass ());
    doReturn(mapper).when(myClass).createObjectMapper();
    Assertions.assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> {
        myClass.getString();
    });
}
```